# How to place highest paying AdSense ad in best performing location?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, ctr, cpc-ads, cpm

So if AdSense places the highest paying ad in the first ad block in your HTML (I’ve read this from multiple sources, if anyone does not agree please let me know why you don’t), how do I make sure the highest paying ad is placed on my best performing location?

In my particular case I have a page we I have one image and two ad blocks, one on each side of the image. The way the HTML goes from top to bottom is Left ad, Image, Right ad. It’s basically a table with three columns and one row ( example here: http://es.wikiarquitectura.com/index.php/Archivo:Central_Saint_Giles_(9).JPG )

**My best performing ad location is the right hand side one, however it’s the left ad block which loads first and therefore displays the highest paying ad.**

How should I go about getting the highest paying ad to my best performing location? Should I switch the ads with JavaScript after the page loads?

Any suggestions are welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to change the position with css. As you are going to be swapping the ad positions I would rename them in the HTML too to save confusion.

```
<div id="imagesequence">
  <div class="prev">...</div> 
  <div class="ad_right">...</div>
  <div class="image">...</div>
  <div class="ad_left">...</div>
  <div class="next">...</div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS you would do;

```
#imagesequence {
  position: relative;
}
.ad_left, .ad_right {
  position: absolute;
}
.ad_left {
  left: 50px; /* to account for the 'prev' div */
}
.ad_right {
  right: 50px;/* to account for the 'next' div */
}
```

I havn't tested but you will probably have to adjust the width on the image block, as the ads will no longer be affecting the position of the image. It will probably we as simple as adding `margin: 0 160px` to the image to account for the width of the ads.

Another option is (as you said) to switch them with javascript. You're already loading jQuery so you could do something like:

```
$(".ad_left").after($(".image"));
$(".ad_right").before($(".image"));
```

I havn't tested that, and I would change the class names to IDs or at least something more specific if you're going to use javascript, to avoid any problems.

I wouldn't worry too much about having the ads next to the image, as it's opened from a gallery it's pretty obvious the ads are ads (*edit: I am in no way an expert on what Google does or thinks, this is just my opinion*). I did notice you're hiding the ad with `display:none;` with media queries. That is against adsense policy unless you are using responsive ads.

> techniques that you’ll want to avoid:
>   Hiding ad units at anytime (e.g. display:none), unless you're
>   implementing a responsive ad unit.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en-GB

I would implement responsive ad code in place of the two blocks and as long as the containing block (`ad_left` or `ad_right`) has `width: 160px; height 600px;` (or whatever ad size you want), the responsive ad will serve the correct size ad anyway, but you are free to hide the ad on smaller screens.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. I will look into it closely but it looks like both solutions will work :)

Answer (score 2):

You're lucky google hasn't issued you a warning (or have they?).

According to this: http://adsense.blogspot.ca/2006/12/ad-and-image-placement-policy.html

Google is advising publishers against aligning images to ads in a way where there the odds of a relationship between the two are good.

What I would suggest is have text in-between the ads and the image or at least have the image not attached to the ads. Also, I'd only recommend just one ad unit if the amount of content on your site is small, otherwise visitors might see your site only as a source of advertisements and the overall loading time will be longer as well.

But since you want a good answer, what I'd suggest is to place the ad unit above the fold (meaning where people can see it without scrolling). And place it in such a way where users wouldn't accidentally click on it. Also, try not to make it too small or too large as you don't want users scrolling in order to see content.

You should see google's adsense policies for more info on what you can and can't do with ad placement.

Comment: Hi @Mike. Thanks for answering. 
No, I have never received a single warning in the many years I’ve been using Adsense.
The reason why there is so little content on the page is because this is only what a user sees when they want to enlarge an image from a main article, that’s where all the original, high quality content is (you can see here http://es.wikiarquitectura.com/index.php/Central_Saint_Giles). Trust me, being a designer I would love to get rid of all the ads, unfortunately for my project to be semi-sustainable I need to be able to pay for hosting and maintainance.

Comment: This answer is the _correct_ answer. @GuillermoCarone - I'm afraid your page is better example of unacceptable implementation, comparing to the official example https://lh5.ggpht.com/LNBnuqPgVf2WNXrlrYLeOyerAaQni7bMNmqo7sLcCy0NHIqwST2G7sq2l7Ca_13-TK8V2Nn1 here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Encouraging_accidental_clicks

Comment: @mike, thanks for following up. Any examples of good ad implementations on similar pages with just one image or an image gallery?